# How best to efficiently extract data from a large SQLite database?

Tags: r, database, sqlite

I am using SQlite to store a large amount of data and am having troubles extracting that data using very simple queries. At the moment, my database is just one table, with about 50million rows and 15 columns. I would like to extract one complete column from this table.

I have tried using RSQlite: `dbGetQuery(db, ‘select qs from CSI’)` where `qs` and `CSI` are my column and table names respectively. Qs are character strings. This query runs for hours before I give up (R version 3.3.3, RSQLite_1.1-2).

I also tried the DB Browser for SQLite (v3.9.1), using the same query and again gave up after a few hours run time. I do not have an IDKey/indexing, but I thought since I want the entire column, this should not have any impact.

I am running on a 64bit Windows machine with 16GB Ram. How can I extract columns from my table within a reasonable time? Or is there a better way I should be storing my data for easy access?

Comment: As a side note.. I had a similar problem and started using `MonetDBLite` (https://www.monetdb.org/blog/monetdblite-r) instead of `SQLite` which made the whole process a lot faster (MonetDB uses a column-orieted storage whereas SQLite uses row-oriented storage)

Comment: Thanks @docendo, I'll give MonetDBLite a go. Do you know is there a good way to import my RSQLite tables directly into MonetDBLite? Creating them was quite time-intensive and I would like to avoid having to do it again. Cheers.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I created a csv export of my sqlite database and then just loaded that into the monetdblite db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a column value, SQLite has to read the row up to the column. So to get the values from all rows, it has to read practically everything.

With an index on this column, you would have a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) that would reduce the amount of data to be read from disk.

If you do not actually need multiple values from the same row, consider storing the columns in different tables, or using a different database.

Comment: Thanks CL, adding the index made things much faster!